# Grails Java 8 Time JSON Simplification

Tags: json, grails, java-time

I'm designing a simple restful reservation system in Grails 3.2.3 and want to use the new Java 8 time library.

```
@Resource(uri='/reservation', formats=['json'])
class Reservation {

    String groupName
    int groupSize
    LocalDateTime dateTime
    int durationMinutes

    static belongsTo = [calendar:ReservationCalendar]

    static constraints = {
        calendar        blank:false, nullable:false
        groupName       blank:false, size:2..30
        groupSize       blank:false, min:1
        durationMinutes blank:false, min:1
        dateTime        validator: {
                            if (it.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(30L))) {
                                return true
                            } else {
                                return ['dateBeforeEarliestReservationTime']
                            }
                        }
    }
}
```

I've inserted the following record in BootStrap.groovy:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    new ReservationCalendar(reservationObject:"reservable item1", reservationUnitsPerSlot:5).save()
    new Reservation(calendar:1, groupName:"testers1", groupSize:2, dateTime:LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2L),  durationMinutes:30).save()
    LocalDateTime maxDaysInFuture;


}
```

Now when I run the application, it all works okay. GET /reservation URI calls the index() action and returns:

```
[{"id":1,"calendar":{"id":1},"dateTime":{"class":"java.time.LocalDateTime","dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":{"enumType":"java.time.DayOfWeek","name":"MONDAY"},"dayOfYear":23,"hour":18,"minute":18,"month":{"enumType":"java.time.Month","name":"JANUARY"},"monthValue":1,"nano":629000000,"second":46,"year":2017,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","class":"java.time.chrono.IsoChronology","id":"ISO"}},"durationMinutes":30,"groupName":"testers1","groupSize":2}]
```

But when I go to POST a new reservation record from some java-agnostic client, I'd rather have some way of not having to know about the underlying datastructure and have some clean input, such as a date string:

```
[{"id":1,"calendar":{"id":1},"dateTime":"01-23-2017 6:30PM CST","durationMinutes":30,"groupName":"testers1","groupSize":2}]
```

I've been reading Grails documentation but there aren't any clear examples on how to customize the input / output of your Resource. I'd like a set of fields like:

```
"dateTime":{"dayOfMonth":23,"month":1,"year":2017,"hour":18,"minute":30},
```

And create the time object from those fields.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is the following:

1) I'm using a regular Date object as dateTime in my domain class. I'm still using Java 8 time api - when I go to do validation and logic on the Date, I just convert it to LocalDateTime each time.

```
LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

2) In BootStrap.groovy, I've registered a friendly output format in my JSON marshaller.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"); 
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Reservation) {
    def returnArray = [:]
    returnArray['groupName'] = it.groupName
    returnArray['groupSize'] = it.groupSize
    returnArray['dateTime'] = dateFormat.format(it.dateTime) // other piece of this is in application.yml (grails.databinding.dateFormats)
    return returnArray
}
```

3) In application.yml, I've defined grails.databinding.dateFormats to contain that same friendly format:

```
grails:
    databinding:
        dateFormats:
            -  "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
```

Result is a JSON that outputs like the following:

```
[{"groupName":"testers1","groupSize":2,"dateTime":"01-24-2017 20:47"}]
```

And performing a POST to add a record, I merely need to offer date time as a formatted string.

```
"dateTime":"01-24-2017 21:47"
```

Feel free to post a groovier solution if you know of one!